# Which OS X version to install on old Mac Mini?

Tags: macos, snow-leopard, mac-mini

I'd like to repurpose a very old Mac Mini 2,1 (1.83 GHz Intel C2D, 4 GB RAM, 320 GB HDD) into a browsing / movie watching machine.

Would I be better off with Snow Leopard or Lion on such an old Mac?

I'm worried that Lion is not an OS at its best iteration, since performance was improved a lot with Mountain Lion, which can't be installed on this Mini due to 32-bit EFI.

Also: should I bother throwing in an SSD?

Comment: I'd just put Yosemite on it, myself.

Comment: @RedEagle2000 you know it won't work :-)

Comment: You're right, I just looked it up on Wikipedia and it's one model newer than yours that can run Yosemite. I just saw the Intel Core 2 Duo spec and just assumed that it could.

Comment: @RedEagle2000 ah sorry, I thought you were being ironic since this is a very old model. Well actually the only reason why this can't run Yosemite is a 32-bit EFI though, which is what killed many Mac Pros too.